# Postsharp express license

Tags: postsharp

I was wondering if you could help – we have previously used a version of Postsharp 2.1.5.1 basic features for the last number of years on a historical application.

All of a sudden, it has started asking for a license key and we cannot find one – it was originally set up by a developer who has long since moved on.

We are trying to use the basic features and don’t require a full license – is this possible?

The version runs on VS 2010 and every time I select an option via the pop up I receive a “Postsharp is configured” message, but when I build the solution, I receive build errors related to Postsharp. Also, the same windows pops up again, and I am taken back to the start of the process i.e. Trial, register or purchase a licence.

Am I missing something in the setup? How do you configure the Express version or download a licence, every time I choose the Express download from the web site I get the full version.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

D

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the latest build of PostSharp 2.1. It will give you the ability to register PostSharp Express without getting a license on our website.